# React doesn't call componentWillMount when render returns another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following components

```
const Dashboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    };
  },

  componentWillMount(){
    var self = this;
    $.get({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/rooms',
      headers: {
        'Auth-Token': self.state.user.backendAccessToken
      },
      success: function(data){
        var rooms = []
        for (var i in data) {
            rooms.push({id: data[i].uid, content: data[i]})
          }
        self.setState({rooms: rooms});
        console.log(rooms);
      }
    })
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <RoomList rooms={this.state.rooms} />
      // <div></div>
    );
  }
});

export default Dashboard;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import RoomLink from './RoomLink';

const RoomList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var roomList = this.props.rooms.map(function(room) {
      return (<RoomLink room={room} />)
    });
    return (
      <div>
      { roomList }
      </div>
    );
  }
});
export default RoomList;
```

when ran, I get `RoomList.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, and the `console.log` and my success callback is never printed. But when I render an empty div instead of the `RoomList` component, the componentWillMount is called and I can see the response in the logs.
Seems like React is not calling `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax call will take time meanwhile child components get rendered with prop rooms as undefined, Need to handle that case.

```
  render: function() {
    var roomList = (this.props.rooms || []).map(function(room) {
    return (<RoomLink room={room} />)
  });
   return (
    <div>
    { roomList }
    </div>
 );
}
```

or

```
render(){
  return(
   <RoomList rooms={this.state.rooms||[]} />
   // <div></div>
  );
}
```